# Estimating the $L^1$ norm of the Dirichlet kernel

Tags: integration, inequality, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Suppose $D_N(x)=\frac{\cos\frac{x}{2}-\cos(N+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}$. How to prove the inequality below$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi|D_N(x)|\text{d}x\leq c\log N$$ for some constant $c>0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By recalling that
$$D_n(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^n
e^{ikx}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)=\frac{\sin\left(\left(n +1/2\right) x \right)}{\sin(x/2)}\tag{1}$$
it is not difficult to locate the stationary points of $D_n(x)$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and conclude that
$$ \left|D_N(x)\right|\leq \min\left(2N+1,\frac{\pi}{|x|}\right)\tag{2}$$
from which:
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|D_N(x)|\,dx\leq \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2N+1}}^{\frac{\pi}{2N+1}}N\,dx+2\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{2N+1}}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{x}\leq 10\log N\tag{3} $$
for any $N\geq 8$.

Comment: Hi Jack.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.  I know that you answered this more than three years ago, but I wanted to ask about Equation $(2)$.  I understand that $|\sin(x/2)|\ge \frac\pi {|x|}$ for $x\in (-\pi,\pi)$ and so $\left|D_N(x)\right|\le \frac\pi {|x|}$.  But as $x\to 0$, clearly $\left|D_N(x)\right|\to 2N+1\ne N+\frac12$.  So, was this just a typo?  And this will affect the bound $C \log(N)$ now.

Comment: @MarkViola: now fixed, there was very little to change.

Comment: Hi Jack.  There's still a problem.  $2N+1$ is not less than $N$.

Comment: So? We just need a logarithmic bound after all

Comment: Yes, Jack.  I understand that.  But the development, as written, is curious.  If we use the bounds in $(2)$, $(3)$ should read $$\begin{align}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |D_N(x)|\,dx &\le 2\int_0^{\pi/(2N+1)}(2N+1)\,dx+2\pi \int_{\pi/(2N+1)}^\pi\frac1x\,dx\\\\&=2\pi \left(1+\log(2N+1)\right)\\\\&<C\log(N)\end{align}$$for some $C$ and for all $N$ greater than some $M$.